# Custom Beamer theme with only mini frames in current section

Tags: beamer

I am trying to customize a beamer theme. I would want something that shows, above the frame title, the name of the current section and the number of slides in the section. I could not find a theme doing exactly that in the theme galery that I explored. There is either the name of the section and the name of the subsection (eg. AnnArbor) or the whole thing with all the names of the sections, possibly of the subsections and the number of frames for each (sub)section (eg. Berlin).

I played a bit with beamer templates and wrote the MWE below.

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=blue!50!white}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=blue!30!white}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{section in head/foot}%
    \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hfil\insertsectionhead\hfil}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{subsection in head/foot}%
    %%
    %% Here I would like to have all the mini frames from the current section.
    %% I know \insertnavigation{...} knows how to do it but I could not find
    %% how this was implemented.
    %%
    \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hfil
      \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}
      \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}
      \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}
      \hfil}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \vskip-1pt%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=2pt,center,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}%
    \strut\insertframetitle\strut%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{First Frame}
  Hello from first frame!
\end{frame}

\section{First Section}

\begin{frame}{Second Frame}
  Hello from second frame!
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Third Frame}
  Hello from third frame!
\end{frame}

\section{Second Section}

\begin{frame}{Fourth Frame}
  Hello from fourth frame!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This MWE gives the following:

[image: Four frames obtained by running the MWE]

I am aware that `\insertnavigation{...}` does what I want and I tried reading its code to find how it was doing it. I was hoping for some beamer template (who knows, maybe `mini frames in current section`?) but I could not find anything.

This seems to be related to [Mini frames in footline - how to only show current subsection?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532170/mini-frames-in-footline-how-to-only-show-current-subsection) which, unfortunately, does not have any answer.
This also looks like [Simple mini frames under frame title beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170122/simple-mini-frames-under-frame-title-beamer) but integrating their `\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal` command into my MWE does not seem to do anything.